# How to display all images if they exist in a folder PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, image, indexing, movie

I have a PHP script that scans a specified Movie directory then displays it styled on a webpage using for loop and php. The code is below. I tried using glob but once I have all the images in an array how do I compare them to the array with all of the movies then if the image and the movie folder match to display the image with the correct name?

```
<?php
// set dir to the directiry you want to index
$dir = 'Movies/';

// scanning the directory you set
$scan = scandir($dir);

// I have this value at 11 because the first movie shows up
// in the 11th file in the array
$file = 11;

// This then removes the first useless files from our array
$scanned = array_slice($scan, $file);

// gets the amount of files
$FileNum = count($scanned);

// display all images and fanart
$images = glob('*.jpg');

// for loop that goes through the array
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $FileNum; $i++) {

      // gives the class for styling
    echo  '<li class="image">';
```

this is problem bit

```
    // check if there is fanart/images in the folders
    if (file_exists($dir . $scanned[$i] . $images)) {

      // if there is images display them styled
      echo '<img id="box1" src="' . $dir . $scanned[$i] . '*.jpg' . '" width="280" height="150" />';
    } else {

      // if not then display default image
    echo '<img id="box1" src="http://placehold.it/280x150" width="280" height="150" />';
  }
            // make the box clickable to where the folder is located
            echo '<a href="'. $dir . $scanned[$i] .'">';

            // display the name of the movie and some JS
             echo '<span class="text-content"><span>' . $scanned[$i] .'<br><br><i class="fa fa-4x  fa-play-circle-o"></i><br><br><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" onclick="openNav()" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></span> </a>';
           }
```

The file structure is as follows

```
      `MOVIES---
                \--random movies
                   \--mp4 and .jpg files`
```

To clarify my question is - Is there a way to check if a file exists, and if it does then put it in an array? I've tried using glob but that can't check if the file exists.

Comment: Can you somehow narrow this down to a more specific, clear question? As is, it feels more like a _"can you code this desired behavior for me?"_ kind of question, but is definitely not very useful to future readers. Check [ask] for some information on how to improve your question.

Comment: I altered the question. To clarify, what I was asking is - Is there a way to check if a file exists, and if it does, put it in an array? I tried using glob but that doesn't account for checking if the file exists.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is an `*` in your `echo` i don't think it needs to be there.

And if your movie directory gets updated, or the images. Then your script does not work anymore. Because of the hard slicing (11th file).

Maybe this will work for you:

```
<?php
// movies
$dir = "movies/";
$files = scandir($dir);

$movies = array();
$images = array();

foreach ($files as $file) {
    // check for the mime type:
    $mime = mime_content_type($dir . $file);

    $type = substr($mime, 0,5);
    $filename = pathinfo($dir . $file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

    if ($type == "video") $movies[] = $file;
    if ($type == "image") $images[] = $filename;
}

foreach ($movies as $movie) {
    $placeholder = true;
    foreach($images as $image) {
        if (strpos($movie, $image) !== false) {
            $placeholder = false;
            continue;
        }
    }
    if ($placeholder) {
        echo $movie . " - placeholder<br>";
    } else {
        echo $movie . " - image<br>";
    }
}
```

It works with the [mime-type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type).

Comment: The problem is I don't have an images folder. When the movies are downloaded they are dumped into a single folder - all mp4/mkv files and all jpg files. So how would I implement this keeping this in mind?

Comment: HeroBrian, with just a bit of effort you should be able to adapt the given code accordingly .